# Does $G\times H \cong G\times K$ imply $H\cong K$ in finite groups?

Tags: finite-groups

The question is as in the title, i.e.

> > Does $G\times H \cong G\times K$ imply $H\cong K$, where $G,H,K$ are finite groups?

We can show that

(1) the abelianizations of $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic

(2) $H/M_S(H)\cong K/M_S(K)$, where $S$ is a non-abelian finite simple group and for a group $G$, $M_S(G)$ is the intersection of all normal subgroups $U$ with $G/U\cong S$; so $G/M_S(G)$ is the maximal quotient of the form $S\times \cdots \times S$.

Comment: I believe that your question was answered in the affirmative in this math.stackexchange post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/cancellation-of-direct-products

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already been answered on MSE.

Comment: I agree to close.

Comment: Of related interest is http://mathoverflow.net/a/48781, although this is for relational structures.  I suspect finite groups also cancel.  Gerhard "Still Amazed After Many Years" Paseman, 2017.02.09.

Comment: Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349855/does-g-times-k-cong-h-times-k-imply-g-cong-h/427640#427640) easy answer.

Comment: @Everyone: As a loyal fan of MO, I feel obliged to point out that this question was answered on MO  two or three months before it was even asked on MSE: http://mathoverflow.net/a/26410/1593

Comment: @Watson Thanks! It was worth asking to get this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is [yes.](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Krull-Remak-Schmidt_theorem)

Hope you can find interesting [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042904/cancellation-of-direct-product-in-grp) too.